# Passing references to express-resources in node.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, node.js, resources, express

How can I pass for example the database reference

```
nano = require('nano')('http://127.0.0.1:5984')
db = nano.use('database')
```

to a resource 'User' (loaded with [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource))?

I tried:

```
app.resource('user', require('./routes/user'), {db: db});
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass `db` to the user.js routing file. What you are doing is passing it to the `app.resource` function.

```
app.resource('user', require('./routes/user')(db));
```

You will have to wrap your user.js file in a function that can receive `db` as a parameter.

```
module.exports = function(db) {
  return {
      index: function(req, res) {}
    , new: function(req, res) {}
    , create: function(req, res) {}
    // etc
  };
};
```

If you don't like the way this is structured, you can also use a middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
```

Comment: wouldn't you have to call next inside of the middleware?